# Excel Hyperlink Function - Display Nice Name?

Tags: hyperlink, excel-formula, excel-2010

I found this formula online. It takes a cell, and handles the hyperlink, based on the excel spreadsheet being in the root folder, so the files being hyperlinked are in that directory (or sub-directory). This is the formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(LEFT(CELL("filename"),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"\","|",LEN(CELL("filename"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(CELL("filename"),"\",""))))) & C2)
```

I would like to have it say something like "Click Here to Open" or something nice. I can certainly handle that in another cell, if that would be easier, but I'm not seeing a way to do that. Anyone know how to handle this?

We don't want the users to see D:\blah\folder\filename.pdf
It looks messy and would like something nicer.

Thanks!

Comment: here is the documentation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f  It gives you the answer.

Comment: If you look below, I answered my question a while ago.

Comment: And my comment preceded your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found it was as simple as adding

,"nicename")

OR

,A2)

to get the name I want.
Duh.